# Some of my custom taxonomies are not showing but still counted in a WPMU set up

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, multisite

I help maintain several sites in a Multisite instance where many of the sites use the same custom theme. In this theme are custom taxonomies that are created automatically when the theme is activated for a site. You cannot delete them because the theme will just recreate them.

My current issue is that some of these custom taxonomies aren't showing up in the admin screen, but are still in the count. 1 under Published and 3 under Drafts. I'm trying to recreate the "missing" taxonomies but when WP creates the URL it adds the "-2" to it and cannot be changed. This is typical behavior when you can see the taxonomy, but since I can't see it, I can't fix it. Does anyone have any idea why I cannot see these custom taxonomies? How do I get them to reappear? They are obviously in the system but are unusable and inaccessible.